# What's the purpose of the blue stars?

Tags: tnns

Whenever you lose your last ball, you're treated to a results screen which indicates how much you were able to collect of orange stars (which can be traded for various temporary or permanent changes in the shop) as well as blue stars (which are much more rare). What's the purpose of the blue stars? Do they have a use?

Comment: What does your tag refer to?

Comment: TNNS is the name of the mobile game this question is about: http://tnns.rabbx.com/